# Can't debug rake task in VS Code

Tags: ruby-on-rails, debugging, visual-studio-code, rake-task

I configured my environment properly to debug rails apps in VS Code.

It works fine for debug Rails Server. When I start the debug, it boots the server and stop at the breakpoints that I have marked.

But, I can't figure out how to debug local files, like rake tasks.
It even runs the task, but it does not stop at the breakpoints.

Below is how I set up my environment.

```
Ubuntu running on WSL2.
VSCode running on windows
```

Installed the extension:

```
Remote - WSL from Microsoft
Ruby from PengLv
```

Installed gems:

```
gem install ruby-debug-ide
gem install debase
```

Gemfile:

```
gem 'ruby-debug-ide'
gem 'debase'`
```

Configuration for debug local file at /.vscode/launch.json:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [
    {
      "name": "Rake fd:test",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rake",
      "useBundler": true,
      "args": ["fd:test"]
    }
  ]
}
```

Rake task itself at /lib/taks/fd.rake:

```
namespace :fd do
  task test: :environment do
    a = 10
    p "teste"
    b = 20
    c = 30
  end
end
```

The configuration for debug Rails server that works properly, just for comparation, is:

```
{
  // Use IntelliSense to learn about possible attributes.
  // Hover to view descriptions of existing attributes.
  // For more information, visit: https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=830387
  "version": "0.2.0",
  "configurations": [

    {
      "name": "Rails server",
      "type": "Ruby",
      "request": "launch",
      "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rails",
      "args": [
        "server"
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

Like I said above, it runs the task, but does not stop on breakpoints.
Anyone can help me out?

Comment: are you able to debug the rake task now?

Answer (score 2):

The [Ruby on Rails debugging in VS Code](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode-recipes/tree/master/debugging-Ruby-on-Rails) suggests you need to add `pathToBundler` and `pathToRDebugIDE`.

Also, VS Code is not wise to RVM environment variables so I always configure env for each configuration.

- note: `gem env` will give you your `GEM PATHS`, used to set `GEM_HOME` and `GEM_PATH` variables
- note: `echo $PATH` - just use the whole path

Doing so would make your configuration look something like:

```
{
  "name": "Rake fd:test",
  "type": "Ruby",
  "request": "launch",
  "cwd": "${workspaceRoot}",
  "program": "${workspaceRoot}/bin/rake",
  "useBundler": true,
  "pathToBundler": "/Users/johng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin/bundle",
  "pathToRDebugIDE": "/Users/johng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@gemset253/gems/ruby-debug-ide-0.7.0/bin/rdebug-ide",
  "args": ["fd:test"],
  "showDebuggerOutput": true,
  "env": {
      "PATH": "/Users/johng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@gemset253/bin:/Users/johng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@global/binƒ/Users/johng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/bin:/Users/johng/.rvm/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin:/usr/sbin:/sbin:/usr/local/sbin",
      "GEM_HOME": "/Users/johng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@gemset253",
      "GEM_PATH": "/Users/johng/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.5.3@gemset253:/Users/johng/.rvm/rubies/ruby-2.5.3/lib/ruby/gems/2.5.0"
  }
}
```